# Trying make character sheet

Tags: python, while-loop

So I have most of the code down pat but when I need to have your skill points run out, it just hasn't been working. For example with the code below every time, I try to get it to end the while loop by putting in a value that makes the lvlpts variable = 0 it just loops. I tried a solution in the if(tolvl == "5"): section of the code but overall nothing seems to be working.

```py
#rpg system to sort out character sheets

#Skill points, assigned number will be earned tho
lvlpts = 10


#These will be leveled up
skills = {
    "ranged weapons handling" : 0,
    "meele weapons handling": 0,
    "speed": 0,
    "strength": 0,
    "endurance": 0,
}

print("Leveling up simulator, doesn't do anything yet")
print(" ")
end = 0
print("These are your skills, level them up. You have", lvlpts, "points left")
#level up loop
while(end == 0):
    print(" ")
    print("Which skills would you like to level up?")
    print(skills)
    print(" ")
    print("To level up Ranged Weapons Handling, type 1, to Level up Meele Weapons Handling, type 2, and so on and so forth. There are 5 categories. Type end to end the program")
    print("")
    #below is the question thingamajig
    tolvl = input("Which skill would you like to level up?")
   
    if(tolvl == "1"):
        amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        #Adds the input cuz is an integer
        if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt)):
            skills["ranged weapons handling"] += amountpt
            lvlpts -= amountpt
            print(" ")
            print("ranged weapons handling =", (skills["ranged weapons handling"]))
            print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
        while(lvlpts <= amountpt):
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
    elif(tolvl == "2"):
        amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt)):
            skills["meele weapons handling"] += amountpt
            lvlpts -= amountpt
            print(" ")
            print("meele weapons handling =", (skills["meele weapons handling"]))
            print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
        while(lvlpts <= amountpt):
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            
    elif(tolvl == "3"):
        amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        #Adds the input cuz is an integer
    
        if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt)):
            skills["speed"] += amountpt
            lvlpts -= amountpt
            print(" ")
            print("speed =", (skills["speed"]))
            print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
        while(lvlpts <= amountpt):
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
    elif(tolvl == "4"):
        amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        #Adds the input cuz is an integer
        if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt)):
            skills["strength"] += amountpt
            lvlpts -= amountpt
            print(" ")
            print("strength =", (skills["strength"]))
            print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
        while(lvlpts <= amountpt):
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
    elif(tolvl == "5"):
        amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        while(lvlpts <= amountpt):
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
            else:
                print("You have no points, redoing the question")
                amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
        if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt)):
            skills["endurance"] += amountpt
            lvlpts -= amountpt
            print(" ")
            print("endurance =", (skills["endurance"]))
            print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
            if(lvlpts == 0):
                break
        
       
    if((tolvl == "end")or(tolvl == "End")):
        break
   
print("task ended successfully")
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause if the problem you're seeing, but I think this check is always `True`: `if((lvlpts >= amountpt)or(amountpt == amountpt))`

Comment: `if` statements and `while` statements in Python DO NOT use outer parentheses like this.  That's a leftover from C and C++, and I don't understand who is teaching this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force conversion of your code that works.  Since the processing for all 5 categories is identical, you could do this all with one loop and a data structure that includes strings to substitute.  I'll add that shortly.

```
#rpg system to sort out character sheets

#Skill points, assigned number will be earned tho
lvlpts = 10

#These will be leveled up
skills = {
    "ranged weapons handling" : 0,
    "melee weapons handling": 0,
    "speed": 0,
    "strength": 0,
    "endurance": 0,
}

print("Leveling up simulator, doesn't do anything yet")
print(" ")
end = 0
print("These are your skills, level them up. You have", lvlpts, "points left")
#level up loop
while not end:
    print("\nWhich skills would you like to level up?")
    print(skills)
    print("\nTo level up Ranged Weapons Handling, type 1, to Level up Meele Weapons Handling, type 2, and so on and so forth. There are 5 categories. Type end to end the program\n")
    #below is the question thingamajig
    tolvl = input("Which skill would you like to level up?")
   
    if tolvl == "1":
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            #Adds the input cuz is an integer
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills["ranged weapons handling"] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print("ranged weapons handling =", (skills["ranged weapons handling"]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")

    elif tolvl == "2":
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills["melee weapons handling"] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print("melee weapons handling =", (skills["meele weapons handling"]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            
    elif tolvl == "3":
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            #Adds the input cuz is an integer
        
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills["speed"] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print("speed =", (skills["speed"]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
    elif tolvl == "4":
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            #Adds the input cuz is an integer
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills["strength"] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print("strength =", (skills["strength"]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
    elif tolvl == "5":
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills["endurance"] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print("endurance =", (skills["endurance"]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
       
    elif tolvl.lower() == "end":
        break
   
print("task ended successfully")
```

A simpler solution:

```
#rpg system to sort out character sheets

#Skill points, assigned number will be earned tho
lvlpts = 10

#These will be leveled up
skills = {
    "ranged weapons handling" : 0,
    "melee weapons handling": 0,
    "speed": 0,
    "strength": 0,
    "endurance": 0,
}

skillnames = list(skills.keys())

print("Leveling up simulator, doesn't do anything yet")
print(" ")
end = 0
print("These are your skills, level them up. You have", lvlpts, "points left")
#level up loop
while not end:
    print("\nWhich skills would you like to level up?  Type 'end' to exit.")
    print(skills)
    for i,n in enumerate(skillnames):
        print( f"{i+1}. {n}" )
    #below is the question thingamajig
    tolvl = input("Which skill would you like to level up?")
   
    if tolvl in "12345":
        name = skillnames[int(tolvl)-1]
        while True:
            amountpt = int(input("How many points would you like to assign?"))
            #Adds the input cuz is an integer
            if lvlpts >= amountpt:
                skills[name] += amountpt
                lvlpts -= amountpt
                print(" ")
                print(name, "=", (skills[name]))
                print("You have", lvlpts, "points left")
                break
            print("You have no points, redoing the question")
       
    elif tolvl.lower() == "end":
        break
   
print("task ended successfully")
```